# Internal Server Error gcloud.datastore.cleanup-indexes when running gcloud datastore cleanup-indexes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

I am trying to remove unnecessary indexes from my app engine project datastore.

I am running the command

```
gcloud datastore cleanup-indexes index.yaml
```

I am getting the below response

```
ERROR: (gcloud.datastore.cleanup-indexes) Server responded with code [500]:
    Internal Server Error.
    <h3>Server Error</h3><p>A server error has occurred.</p>
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

This error message seems to be generated by a known internal issue which is currently being investigated.

You can take a look on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112246195) ticket that has been created to report this unexpected behavior. Additionally, I recommend you to use the **Star this issue**  feature by clicking on the star button located at the header section of the ticket in order to receive comments and status updates about the issue.

- Issue Tracker :

[image: Star this issue]